# How to "custom" the ModalPosition of Blazored Modal to be the center of the top?

Tags: modal-dialog, blazor, blazored

Want to use Modal for the delete confirmation in my CRUD application and need to put the modal window on the center of the bottom.
Looks like Blazored Modal is a good package and it provides TopLeft, TopRight, BottomLeft, BottomRight, Center and Custom.
How to use "Custom" to make my Modal dialog to appear on the center of the top?

Comment: Documentation is [here](https://github.com/Blazored/Modal). Basically, if you use `ModalPosition.Custom`, you must add a corresponding CSS class. `PositionCustomClass = "custom-position-class"`